# Failing to mock a library function

Tags: python, logging, mocking

I am writing unit tests for a class that implements a wrapper to logger (and does something more). However, as I run the test by mocking the `info` function in `Logger` class, it is not working. I want to assert that mocked function has been called, but it is not.

module

```
import http
import logging
from flask import request

class MyLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def generate_log(self, request_ctx, log_msg, outcome):
        # Console Log
        if outcome is http.HTTPStatus.OK:
            self.log.info(log_msg)
```

Test

```
class TestMyLogger(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_generate_log(self):
        
        request_mock = patch.object(flask, "request")

        with patch('my_module_name.log.info') as console_logger_mock:
            my_log = MyLogger()
            succ_log_str = "success log"
            my_log.generate_log(request_mock, succ_log_str, 200)
            console_logger_mock.assert_called_with(succ_log_str)
```

Error Seen

```
_mock_self = <MagicMock name='info' id='4466296400'>, args = ('success log',)
kwargs = {}, expected = "info('success log')"

    def assert_called_with(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs):
        """assert that the mock was called with the specified arguments.
    
            Raises an AssertionError if the args and keyword args passed in are
            different to the last call to the mock."""
        self = _mock_self
        if self.call_args is None:
            expected = self._format_mock_call_signature(args, kwargs)
>           raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
E           AssertionError: Expected call: info('success log')
E           Not called
```

Comment: No. it's right there. `my_log.generate_log(request_mock, succ_log_str, 200)`. See the last 200

Comment: Can you change in the if statement `is` to `==`. Comparing an Enumeration with is in this way doesn’t work.

Comment: Yes, it helped fix the error.